# ColdFusion: How to parse dd/mm/yyyy formated date?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I found the [ParseDateTime](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7843.html) function but it only parses a date/time string according to the English (U.S.) locale conventions.

How to parse the date which is in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Try out this:

```
<cfset TestdateFrom = ParseDateTime("10/9/2010") />
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="30" step="1">
    <cfset TestdateFrom = DateAdd( "d", 1, TestdateFrom ) />
    #TestdateFrom#<br/>
</cfloop>
```

In CF9 there is a [LSParseDateTime](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-70e3.html) function.

I don't know whether this will help me or not.

At last should I use java library for this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, or what do you want as an end result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success with this technique for dealing with (UK formatted) dates entered as free text:

```
<cfset SetLocale("English (UK)")>
<cfset valid = true>

<!--- Convert DD-MM-YYYY or DD.MM.YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY --->
<cfset dt = replacelist(dt, ".,-", "/,/")>

<!--- count date elememnts (must be 3 - LSParseDateTime will make potentially incorrect assumptions otherwise) --->
<cfif listlen(dt, "/") neq 3>
    <!--- wrong number of elements --->
    <cfset valid = false>
<cfelse>
    <!--- Correct number of elements so try to interpret as date/time object --->   
    <cftry>
        <cfset dt = LSParseDateTime(dt)> 
        <cfcatch type="Expression">
            <cfset valid = false>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfif>
```

If valid is true at the end of this, the string date representation in dt has been converted to a date/time object.  The replacelist step allows for the date to be entered as DD.MM.YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY as well as DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Forgot to mention that LSParseDateTime has been available since at least version 4.5 in case anyone reads this and thinks it's new in CF9

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this is working:

```
<cfset formatter = createObject("java","java.text.SimpleDateFormat")>
<cfset formatter.init("dd/MM/yyyy")>
<cfset newDate = formatter.parse("10/09/2010")>
#newDate#
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've had good success with this approach - it is flexible and works for all kinds of formatted dates, which can't be said for the pure ColdFusion approach.

Answer (score 5):

If your format is consistent, you can also do something like this:

```
<cfset dy=listGetAt(dateString,1,"/")>
<cfset mo=listGetAt(dateString,2,"/")>
<cfset yr=listGetAt(dateString,3,"/")>

<cfset myDate=createDate(yr,mo,dy)>
```

But, really, [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202593/coldfusion-how-to-parse-dd-mm-yyyy-formated-date/4202946#4202946) is the best.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use lsParseDateTime(). This is the locale specific date parser.

You can either pass a locale straight into the second parameter of the function or use setlocale() to set it for the request.

You'll probably find it useful to look at the other LS prefixed functions too.